# sorting STL container with pair of pairs

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

This is my first time using C++ STL `priority_queue()` and I am a bit confused about this specific piece of code I came across (but I believe this has nothing to do with pq, and it should be applicable to all containers (vector,sets,etc)):

```
priority_queue<pair<int, pair<int, int> >,
            vector<pair<int, pair<int, int> > >,
            greater<pair<int, pair<int, int> > > > pq;
```

Lets say I have `pq.push_back(make_pair(a,make_pair(b,c)))`. In case there is clash of `a`, then will the comparison rule extend to the second pair and sorting will be done on the basis of `b` and then `c`?

Comment: Don't you want `std::tuple<int, int, int>` instead of `pair<int, pair<int, int>>` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 : Yes that could serve the purpose in most cases, but this was just for the clarification of the concepts and I indeed found someone implementing it this way. (To suggest someone avoid ternary operators, I must first understand what ternary operators are? :) Hence I posted this for my clarification. Hope it will help future visitors as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question basically boils down to: How are `std::pair`s sorted, ie what is the result of `a > b` for two pairs (note that `std::greater` just calls `operator>`).

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) on `std::pair::operator>` :

> Compares lhs and rhs lexicographically, that is, compares the first
>   elements and only if they are equivalent, compares the second
>   elements.

And this naturally extends to nested pairs. Hence...

> Lets say I have pq.push_back(make_pair(a,make_pair(b,c))). In case
>   there is clash of a, then will the comparison rule extend to the
>   second pair and sorting will be done on the basis of b and then c?

Yes. If two elements have equal `a` then the `second` of the outermost pair (ie `(b,c)`) will be compared.

Answer (score 1):

> In case there is clash of a, then will the comparison rule extend to the second pair and sorting will be done on the basis of b and then c?

Exactly. `std::greater` defaults to `operator >`, which, in case of `std::pair`, [implements lexicographical comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) - that is, compares the first, and if the first coincide, compares the second.

Answer (score 0):

The class `priority_queue` needs a comparison method. By default `std::less` will be used but you can overrride it.

Using `std::pair` will imply using the default comparison used by std::pair: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/operators/

I think this should respond to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: the pairs of pairs are sorted by lexicographic order on (a, b, c).
Take a look at [std::greater](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) which actually calls [std::pair::operator>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp).